# Get Button Scrolling Height in a Container onclick with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get scrolling position of a button in div on clicking it with only javascript Function. When i'm click on any button in this div, scroll bar set on clicked button position. Like this click on another button then scroll bar scrolled to there position.

```css
.box {
  background:#00eef3;
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box">
  <button type="submit">1</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">2</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">3</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">4</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">5</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">6</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">7</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">8</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">9</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">10</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">11</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">12</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">13</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">14</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">15</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">16</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">17</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">18</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">19</button><br/>
  <button type="submit">20</button><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: nothing comes my mind to can't have any javascript code.

Comment: @prashantkushwah Your question is not clear. Where you required to set the position? If I click on '5', do you require the button go top means scrollbar gets down and first visible button will be '5' ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mulekatumo/edit?html,js,output are you looking for something like this ?

Comment: i'm tried this in my pc too. if I get any success then i add javascript code in this question

Comment: @ZAiDChauhan yes i want that you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I guess this is what you are looking.**

```js
// self executing function here
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here
  document.querySelectorAll('button[type=submit]').forEach(function(buttonElement){
     buttonElement.addEventListener('click', updateScroll.bind(this));
   });
   
   function updateScroll(e){
    var _top = e.target.offsetTop - e.target.offsetHeight/2;
    document.querySelector('#box').scrollTop = _top;
   }
})();
```

```css
.box    {
                background:#00eef3;
                width:150px;
                height:200px;
                overflow-y:auto;
            }
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box">
        <button type="submit">1</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">2</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">3</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">4</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">5</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">6</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">7</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">8</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">9</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">10</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">11</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">12</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">13</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">14</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">15</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">16</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">17</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">18</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">19</button><br/>
        <button type="submit">20</button><br/>
    </div>
```